# Log4j - blocking a particular class

Tags: log4j

I have a Tomcat webapp that uses Log4j logging and is configured via a `log4j.properties` file. I'd rather it were configured via an xml file, which I understand better, but I don't have the time or inclination to change it.

The root logger is set up this way:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
```

This is what I want, with one exception: A class I recently started using (`AmazonHttpClient`) is spewing out way too many `INFO` logs, and I want to restrict just that class to `WARN` level only, without changing anything else.

How do I do it?

I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
log4j.rootLogger.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient=WARN
```

I also tried all of these:

```
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient=WARN
log4j.rootLogger.AmazonHttpClient=WARN
log4j.logger.AmazonHttpClient=WARN
```

What's the answer?

Comment: `log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient=WARN` *should* have worked, I think.